# how to handle radio button group in a ng-repeater Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an page where i need to submit all the employees that need to retire or not to retire. I am trying to show employee name and radio button list for each employee with options retire and notretire.

```html
<div class="body" ng-repeat="employee in EmployeesList">
   <div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px;">            
     <label>{{employee.name}}</label>     
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <label class="radio-inline"><input name="radioGroup" type="radio" id="Retired" 
       checked="checked" ng-model="$parent.status" value="RETIRED"/><strong>RETIRED</strong></label>
     <label class="radio-inline"><input name="radioGroup" type="radio" id="NotRetiring"
       ng-model="$parent.status" value="NOTRETIRING"/><strong>NOT RETIRING</strong></label>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="Submit()">OK</button>
   <button type="button" ng-click="cancel()">CANCEL</button>
</div>


Controller:

 $scope.EmployeesList = EmployeeService.getEmployeeList();

 $scope.Submit = function () {

        angular.forEach($scope.EmployeesList, function (employee, index) {                                                          
            var employeeid = employee.id;
            var date = new Date();
             
            var employeeResponse =
            {
                EmployeeID: employeeid,
                DateEntered: date,
                Status: $scope.status
            }
            
            EmployeeService.Submit(employeeResponse).then(function() {
                
            });
        }
});
```

When i try to select status of each employee whether he is RETIRED or not, its not doing as it suppose to do. If i change status on second Employee then the status of first employee is loosing its status. Now I need to see "RETIRED" as Default selection for all Employees and need to modify the status for each employee as i need. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You want to remember status for each employee, so try:

```
<div class="body" ng-repeat="employee in EmployeesList">
   <div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px;">            
     <label>{{employee.name}}</label>     
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <label class="radio-inline"><input name="radioGroup" type="radio" id="Retired" 
       checked="checked" ng-model="employee.status" value="RETIRED"/><strong>RETIRED</strong></label>
     <label class="radio-inline"><input name="radioGroup" type="radio" id="NotRetiring"
       ng-model="employee.status" value="NOTRETIRING"/><strong>NOT RETIRING</strong></label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: masitko: there is no status  field in the EmployeeList. I will be inserting into there datavase table with employeedetails and status.